# PHPでデータベースから配列で取得したいが、一文字しか取得できない

Tags: php

**前提**
失礼いたします。
PHP初心者です。
現在ECサイトを作るため、商品一覧ページを作成しています。

**実現したいこと**
データベースに格納しているデータを配列で取得したい。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**
配列で取得しようとしたところ、１文字の文字列しか取得できません。

**例**

```
var_dump($pro_name[[0])

//結果
「item1」という名前の「i」だけ出力される
```

**該当のソースコード**

```
<?php
    $dsn='mysql:dbname=shop;host=localhost;charset=utf8';
    $user='root';
    $password='';
    $dbh=new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql='SELECT name,price,image FROM mst_product ';
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $rec=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    $pro_name=$rec['name'];
    $pro_price=$rec['price'];
    $pro_image_name=$rec['image'];

  
    
    $dbh=null;


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="inner-wrap">
<h2 class="itemarea-list">商品一覧</h2>
<div class="item-area">


<div class ="item-area-item">
<?php for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
?>
    <?php echo $pro_image_name[$i].'<br>'; ?>
 <?php echo $pro_name[$i].'<br>';?> 
    <?php echo $pro_price[$i].'<br>'; ?>
<?php
    }
?>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
<br>
<a href="shop_cartlook.php">カートを見る</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**試したこと**
$rec=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);を(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)やfetchallにしてみましたが変わらずでした。
お手数ですがどなたかご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/7htlqi3p24ibii) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 補足: 最初の10行を表示しようとしてforループにされているようですが、`$stmt->fetch()`はデータを1行ずつ取得します。[マニュアル](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/pdostatement.fetch.php#:~:text=%E4%BE%8B2%20%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E3%81%AA%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BD%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E8%A1%8C%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)には複数行取得の例があるのでご確認ください。

Answer (score 3):

変数が配列でなければ、オフセットアクセスアクセスせずに
普通に`var_dump($pro_name)`とすれば文字列が出力されます。

$pro_name[0]のように、文字列の格納された変数を配列の様にオフセットアクセスすると１文字ずつ文字を取り出す事ができます。
https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Answer (score 0):

```
$rec=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

上記、fetchAllで全部取っておいて、下記３つは不要

```
$pro_name=$rec['name'];        // 不要
$pro_price=$rec['price'];      // 不要
$pro_image_name=$rec['image']; // 不要
```

で出力はこんな感じで回せば良いです。

```
<?php echo $rec[$i]['name'].'<br>'; ?>
<?php echo $rec[$i]['plice'].'<br>'; ?>
<?php echo $rec[$i]['image'].'<br>'; ?>
```

それかもうこれだけ

```
while ($rec = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    <?php echo  $rec['name'].'<br>'; ?>
    <?php echo  $rec['plice'] .'<br>'; ?>
}
```